# Setup doesn't see windows

Tags: dual-boot

So I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 and when I load setup from DVD and it doesn't offer me to install it alongside with Windows 7 64bit. So how to overcome this, I found few solutions but don't know which to use. One of them is to chose "something else" on setup and select unallocated space to install Ubuntu on it, if I do that will I be able to boot Ubuntu and windows because some of users states that after install and power off and on boots directly to windows and sometimes directly to Ubuntu. So what to do?

Comment: In your BIOS, is your disk set to RAID, or something else? Or, does your Windows C: drive need to have chkdsk run on it?

Comment: are they both booting in the sme mode? EFI vs Legacy?

Comment: I can't boot to BIOS (the one with blue and silver colors) it boots me to white screen with categories on left. I think it's setup too boot on UEFI but when I want to boot from CD I hit F12 and it gives me option to boot from CD but it's under legacy and under UEFI is only widows boot.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Are your disks set to RAID?

Comment: If you ask about SATA operation it's set to "ACHI" not "RAID on"

Comment: Use Rufus to prepare a USB stick instead. Make sure the GPT/UEFI option is selecting before proceeding. Boot and install in UEFI mode, the same as your already installed OS.

Comment: @MichaelBay solved see my answer

Answer (score -1):

Honest mistake. I was using 32 bit Ubuntu on CD and my Windows was 64 bit. I burned 64 bit Ubuntu to CD and now setup does see Windows.

Comment: Please either delete or seriously [edit] this supposed answer. Here's the thing: You should use 64-bit OSes because **the hardware is 64-bit**, it has nothing to do with the architecture of the already installed OS. Posting it like this shows total ignorance and may induce in error other newbies. Then there's the media: Why do you insist on using DVDs? (yes, you mentioned CD but that's dumb because Ubuntu doesn't fit in one CD since many years ago) A USB stick is much faster and recommended for any modern PC.

Comment: Here is the thing, this switch form 32bit to 64bit Ubuntu solved my problem where I wasn't able to see Windows from Ubuntu setup (since I was using 32bit Ubuntu CD) when I used 64bit Ubuntu CD it offered me an option to install alongside windows which is 64bit.